# I have a question please. new to assembly and gdb

Tags: linux, assembly, gdb

currently working on binary bomb and I just noticed I'm on the call that will detonate the bomb. is there a way to avoid this?

```
(gdb) disas
...
=> 0x0000000000400f17 <+27>: callq  0x401604 <explode_bomb>"
```

[image]
check the image for complete instruction please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you're asking if you can skip the instruction which calls the function `explode_bomb`, you can use `jmp` in gdb , `jump *0x1234` will jump to instruction at address `0x1234`, so you can skip whatever instruction you like.